# Error:(48) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android

Getting this error **Error:(48) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)**
for below mentioned layout. Preview showing correctly. Not able to understand why I am getting this error. I made sure that every view or view closed properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
card_view:cardElevation="2sp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:contentPadding="5dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilepic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content "
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profilepic"
            android:text="prashanth" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quote"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/details"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:text="jalkdjlajflkdajf akjfdlajfljal alfjk" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/quote"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        < TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="time started" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bronze_coin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/bronze_coin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/bronze_coin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/bronze_coin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Your time id TextView have space in begin of tag...just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a node starting with "< TextView" instead of "<TextView".

In addition, you'll need to define the android prefix as a namespace in the RelativeLayout node, e.g.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these solutions:

*First*, set the tools:context attribute on your CardLayout like this:

```
tools:context=".MyActivity"
```

*Second*, add this code in your CardLayout just under your xmlns:android property

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

*Third*, search your xml for blank spaces after opening tag '<' or before closing tag '>' (this may be a problem sometimes)

And finally clean your project and Build it again.